# Where is the relationship for a lesson in a child course to a lesson in a parent course(the metacourse) in Moodle?

Tags: php, moodle, meta

I am currently working on a system where all the resources/course materials of a course is placed inside a metacourse. I am trying get the resources from the metacourse/parent course and link it to a lesson. For example, I have the courseID = 92 and lessonID = 276. I look into the course_meta table and find that the parent courseID = 50. I use the parent courseID in the course_modules table to find ALL the resources. Now, my problem is here. I am able to find ALL the resources for a course given that I first find the parent courseID, however, how do I know that a given resource is for lessonID = 276? How do I know the lesson in the metacourse = the lesson in the child course? Where do I look in the table?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not one-hundred percent sure I understand your question completely, but I'll hazard some help. Feel free to ask for clarification if I'm off the mark.

The metacourse system in Moodle is mostly for convenience of enrolment. Either enrolments on a parent course are passed onto all child courses, or the reverse: an enrolment on any child course also appears in the parent course. Actually, from experience, they're a major pain even for doing this and there's almost certainly a better way of doing it.

As far as I know, this is as far as it goes, so there will be no formal relationship between resources in those parent/child courses even if they're identical.

The only way you can look for the same resource in different courses in going to be to do something like match on the `name` field. This, of course, isn't completely reliable (but is actually something I've had to do in some cases).

I wonder if there might be a better way of organising your resources to achieve what you're trying to do. Of course, I don't know the details, but if having just copy of the lesson in the parent course and using groups to keep students separate could do the job then it will greatly decrease the complexity.